# Replacing default javascript function with your own custom function

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have a `<textarea>` element in a webpage that has hover, click and other events attached to it. When I add my own custom even listener to the same element for, let's say hover, it obviously executes my custom functionality but it also executes the default behavior, which is undesirable. I just need it to execute my piece of code and not the default one.

P.S. I am working on a chrome extension that needs to interact with this textarea. Mentioning this if it's relevant in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Add `event.preventDefault();` to your custom function. More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault